# Smack4.1.7 No response received within reply timeout

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am using smack 4.1.7 as my xmpp library on android and openfire as my server. I get an exception when I try a forceful reconnection as soon as the device goes online from airplane mode. In the normal workflow, I don't get this exception. I want my app to support offline mode so I have to make sure that there is a smooth transition from offline to online mode. I use airplane mode to test this scenario.

I am using reconnection manager to handle reconnecting at a fixed delay of 20 seconds. I force reconnection because I don't want the user to wait 20 seconds for the xmpp reconnection if the user is already in the app. This is why I rely on reconnection manager to reconnect only when the app is in background. I hope this helps in understanding what I am trying to do here.

I am posting the stack trace with Smack debug mode enabled on android:

```
07-26 13:55:45.154 com.myapp.xmpptest I/XmppService: Network state changed. Network connected.
07-26 13:55:45.154 com.myapp.xmpptest I/XmppService: Before xmppConnection connect.....
07-26 13:55:45.174 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 14

07-26 13:55:45.324 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: SENT (0): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='myapp.com' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='eaf60f002867230766bb74b4419dffca@myapp.com' xml:lang='en'>

07-26 13:55:45.404 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: RECV (0): <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="myapp.com" id="bde2ec9" xml:lang="en" version="1.0">

07-26 13:55:45.484 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: RECV (0): <stream:features><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"><required/></starttls><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanis ms></stream:features>

07-26 13:55:45.484 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: SENT (0): <starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'></starttls>
07-26 13:55:45.564 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: RECV (0): <proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
07-26 13:55:46.174 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 13

07-26 13:55:46.194 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: SENT (0): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='myapp.com' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='eaf60f002867230766bb74b4419dffca@myapp.com' xml:lang='en'>

07-26 13:55:46.274 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: RECV (0): <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="myapp.com" id="bde2ec9" xml:lang="en" version="1.0"><stream:features><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanis ms><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression><auth xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth"/></stream:features>

07-26 13:55:46.284 com.myapp.xmpptest D/xmppTest: XmppConnectionListener connectionConnected()
07-26 13:55:46.284 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection connected (0)

07-26 13:55:46.284 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: SENT (0): <auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='PLAIN'>HJKSHGFJHJGKHDJHGJEHJKRHGJKFDHGhjshjkghruiehskrjgbjkeh5j4568o gjkfhdsgh589wwghjfdghsuHJKSHFIREHGHRUEIghgfhjdgsu87489YUFSfh483fhj==</auth>

07-26 13:55:47.174 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 12
07-26 13:55:47.174 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 0

07-26 13:55:51.293 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'.

07-26 13:55:51.293 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java: 250)
07-26 13:55:51.293 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.loginNonAnonymously(XMPPTCPConnect ion.java:374)
07-26 13:55:51.293 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java :456)
07-26 13:55:51.293 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java :414)
07-26 13:55:51.293 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection. java:863)
07-26 13:55:51.293 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.ja va:364)
07-26 13:55:51.293 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at com.myapp.xmpp.XmppService.connectAndAuthenticate(XmppService.java:492)
07-26 13:55:51.293 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at com.myapp.xmpp.XmppService$2.run(XmppService.java:195)
07-26 13:55:51.293 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-26 13:55:51.293 com.myapp.xmpptest I/XmppService: Before xmppConnection login.....

07-26 13:55:51.293 com.myapp.xmpptest W/AbstractXMPPConnection: Connection closed with error
                                                                            javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x9abd4400: I/O error during system call, Connection timed out
                                                                                at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketIm pl.java:753)
                                                                                at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:231)
                                                                                at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:325)
                                                                                at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.ObservableReader.read(ObservableReader.java:41)
                                                                                at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.fillBuffer(KXmlParser.java:1515)
                                                                                at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.peekType(KXmlParser.java:992)
                                                                                at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:349)
                                                                                at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:313)
                                                                                at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPC onnection.java:1173)
                                                                                at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPCon nection.java:952)
                                                                                at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnecti on.java:967)
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

07-26 13:55:51.293 com.myapp.xmpptest D/xmppTest: XmppConnectionListener connectionClosedOnError()
07-26 13:55:51.293 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x9abd4400: I/O error during system call, Connection timed out
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketIm pl.java:753)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:231)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:325)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.ObservableReader.read(ObservableReader.java:41)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.fillBuffer(KXmlParser.java:1515)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.peekType(KXmlParser.java:992)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:349)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:313)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPC onnection.java:1173)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPCon nection.java:952)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnecti on.java:967)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection closed due to an exception (0)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x9abd4400: I/O error during system call, Connection timed out
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketIm pl.java:753)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:231)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:325)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.ObservableReader.read(ObservableReader.java:41)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.fillBuffer(KXmlParser.java:1515)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.peekType(KXmlParser.java:992)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:349)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:313)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPC onnection.java:1173)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPCon nection.java:952)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnecti on.java:967)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NotConnectedException: Client is not, or no longer, connected.
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.throwNotConnectedExce ptionIfDoneAndResumptionNotPossible(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1248)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.throwNotConnectedExceptionIfApprop riate(XMPPTCPConnection.java:345)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java :451)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java :414)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.ReconnectionManager$2.run(ReconnectionManager.java:248)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest D/xmppTest: XmppConnectionListener reconnectionFailed()
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NotConnectedException: Client is not, or no longer, connected.
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: Reconnection failed due to an exception (0)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.throwNotConnectedExce ptionIfDoneAndResumptionNotPossible(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1248)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err: at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NotConnectedException: Client is not, or no longer, connected.
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.throwNotConnectedExce ptionIfDoneAndResumptionNotPossible(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1248)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.throwNotConnectedExceptionIfApprop riate(XMPPTCPConnection.java:345)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java :451)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java :414)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.ReconnectionManager$2.run(ReconnectionManager.java:248)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.throwNotConnectedExceptionIfApprop riate(XMPPTCPConnection.java:345)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java :451)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at com.myapp.xmpp.XmppService.connectAndAuthenticate(XmppService.java:538)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at com.myapp.xmpp.XmppService$2.run(XmppService.java:195)
07-26 13:55:51.303 com.myapp.xmpptest W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 
07-26 13:55:52.303 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 19
07-26 13:55:53.303 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 18
07-26 13:55:54.303 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 17
07-26 13:55:55.303 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 16
07-26 13:55:56.313 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 15
07-26 13:55:57.313 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 14
07-26 13:55:58.313 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 13
07-26 13:55:59.313 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 12
07-26 13:56:00.313 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 11
07-26 13:56:01.313 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 10
07-26 13:56:02.313 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 9
07-26 13:56:03.313 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 8
07-26 13:56:04.313 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 7
07-26 13:56:05.313 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 6
07-26 13:56:06.313 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 5
07-26 13:56:07.313 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 4
07-26 13:56:08.323 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 3
07-26 13:56:09.313 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 2
07-26 13:56:10.313 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 1
07-26 13:56:11.323 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 0
07-26 13:56:11.323 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 0
 
07-26 13:56:11.373 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: SENT (0): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='myapp.com' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='eaf60f002867230766bb74b4419dffca@myapp.com' xml:lang='en'>

07-26 13:56:11.403 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: RECV (0): <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="myapp.com" id="8dbb465e" xml:lang="en" version="1.0">

07-26 13:56:11.433 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: RECV (0): <stream:features><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"><required/></starttls><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanis ms></stream:features>

07-26 13:56:11.443 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: SENT (0): <starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'></starttls>
07-26 13:56:11.473 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: RECV (0): <proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>

07-26 13:56:11.963 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: SENT (0): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='myapp.com' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='eaf60f002867230766bb74b4419dffca@myapp.com' xml:lang='en'>

07-26 13:56:12.003 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: RECV (0): <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="myapp.com" id="8dbb465e" xml:lang="en" version="1.0"><stream:features><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanis ms><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression><auth xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth"/></stream:features>

07-26 13:56:12.003 com.myapp.xmpptest D/xmppTest: XmppConnectionListener connectionConnected()
07-26 13:56:12.003 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection connected (0)

07-26 13:56:12.003 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: SENT (0): <auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='PLAIN'>HJKSHGFJHJGKHDJHGJEHJKRHGJKFDHGhjshjkghruiehskrjgbjkeh5j4568o gjkfhdsgh589wwghjfdghsuHJKSHFIREHGHRUEIghgfhjdgsu87489YUFSfh483fhj==</auth>

07-26 13:56:12.223 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: RECV (0): <success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"/>

07-26 13:56:12.223 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: SENT (0): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='myapp.com' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='eaf60f002867230766bb74b4419dffca@myapp.com' id='8dbb465e' xml:lang='en'>

07-26 13:56:12.253 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: RECV (0): <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="myapp.com" id="8dbb465e" xml:lang="en" version="1.0"><stream:features><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/></stream:features>

07-26 13:56:12.253 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: SENT (0): <iq id='H0v5c-22' type='set'><bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'><resource>d73d639de6435579</resource>< /bind></iq>

07-26 13:56:12.283 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: RECV (0): <iq type="result" id="H0v5c-22" to="myapp.com/8dbb465e"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><jid>eaf60f002867230766bb74b4419dffca@myapp.com/d73d639de6435579</jid></bind></iq>

07-26 13:56:12.293 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: SENT (0): <iq id='H0v5c-24' type='set'><session xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session'/></iq>
07-26 13:56:12.323 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: RECV (0): <iq type="result" id="H0v5c-24" to="eaf60f002867230766bb74b4419dffca@myapp.com/d73d639de6435579"/>
07-26 13:56:12.323 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: User logged (0):eaf60f002867230766bb74b4419dffca@myapp.com:5222/d73d639de6435579
07-26 13:56:12.323 com.myapp.xmpptest D/xmppTest: XmppConnectionListener authenticated(). resumed : false
07-26 13:56:12.323 com.myapp.xmpptest D/xmppTest: joining control room
07-26 13:56:12.323 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: XMPPConnection authenticated (0)
07-26 13:56:12.323 com.myapp.xmpptest D/xmppTest: XmppConnectionListener reconnectionSuccessful()

07-26 13:56:12.323 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: SENT (0): <presence id='H0v5c-26'><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack' ver='zIfK69gJkJ5OCxMILmZOsZ9HBlU='/></presence>
07-26 13:56:12.323 com.myapp.xmpptest D/SMACK: SENT (0): <presenceto='controlroom@conference.myapp.com/eaf60f002867230766bb74b4419dffca@myapp.com' id='H0v5c-27' type='unavailable'></presence>
```

If I understand correctly from the logs, I get the exception when I try to reconnect immediately in network change event when the device connects to the internet from airplane mode. However it does eventually connect via reconnection manager. The code that I am using to trigger xmpp connect and login is as follows:

```
// The network monitor

    private BroadcastReceiver networkMonitor = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (isOnline && !Utilities.isOnline(AbstractActivity.this)) {
                isOnline = false;
            } else if (!isOnline && Utilities.isOnline(AbstractActivity.this)) {
                // Trigger only when going from offline to online
                isOnline = Utilities.isOnline(AbstractActivity.this);

                // Re-establish the xmpp connection if it was disconnected
                if (isOnline ) {
                    connectAndAuthenticate();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public void connectAndAuthenticate() {
        if(xmppConnection==null){
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder builder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                                                                                        .setUsernameAndPassword(hashedUserName, getPassword())
                                                                                        .setServiceName(serviceName)
                                                                                        .setHost(getCoreServer())
                                                                                        .setSendPresence(true)
                                                                                        .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required)
                                                                                        .setPort(Integer.parseInt(port))
                                                                                        .setResource(getDeviceID());
          if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            builder.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
          }

          XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = builder.build();

          xmppConnection = new MVXMPPTCPConnection(config);

          // Disable the roster
          Roster.getInstanceFor(xmppConnection).setRosterLoadedAtLogin(false);

          ReconnectionManager reconnectionManager = ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(xmppConnection);
          reconnectionManager.enableAutomaticReconnection();
          reconnectionManager.setReconnectionPolicy(ReconnectionManager.ReconnectionPolic y.FIXED_DELAY);
          reconnectionManager.setFixedDelay(20);

          PingManager pingManager = PingManager.getInstanceFor(xmppConnection);
          pingManager.registerPingFailedListener(this);
          pingManager.setPingInterval(60);

          // Instantiates a ChatStateManager.
          ChatStateManager.getInstance(xmppConnection);
  }

        // connect
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Before xmppConnection connect.....");
            xmppConnection.connect();
            Log.i(TAG, "After xmppConnection connect.....");
        } catch (SmackException.AlreadyConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // login
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Before xmppConnection login.....");
            xmppConnection.login(hashedUserName, getPassword(), getDeviceID());
            Log.i(TAG, "After xmppConnection login.....");
            // return
        } catch (SmackException.AlreadyLoggedInException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException.ConnectionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am getting a lot of these errors. Can anyone please help me out here. I have searched a lot on google with hardly any result. I also posted this problem on Smack Support community but haven't heard back from anyone yet.

PS: I have exhausted the number of lines that I can add in the body part here, so I am posting openfire server logs as an answer as I do not know how to include everything in proper format without breaking them like this. I apologize for it.

Comment: since u r using reconnection manager, why are you explicity login then on connection change? won't reconnection manager handle that?

Comment: The reconnection manager will make a reconnection attempt every 20 seconds. When user is within the app I don't want the user to wait 20 seconds till the app comes online so I try to connect as soon as I get notified that the internet connection is established. I rely on reconnection manager to reconnect mainly while the app is in background. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Logs from the openfire server:

```
2016.08.24 07:24:30 org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.ConnectionHandler - ConnectionHandler reports IOException for session: (SOCKET, R: /70.198.72.125:5004, L: /172.16.23.40:5222, S: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:5222)
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake failed.
at org.apache.mina.filter.SSLFilter.messageReceived(SSLFilter.java:416)
at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(Ab stractIoFilterChain.java:299)
at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain.access$1100(AbstractIoFilt erChain.java:53)
at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceive d(AbstractIoFilterChain.java:648)
at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain$HeadFilter.messageReceived (AbstractIoFilterChain.java:499)
at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(Ab stractIoFilterChain.java:299)
at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain.fireMessageReceived(Abstra ctIoFilterChain.java:293)
at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.read(SocketIoProcessor.j ava:228)
at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.process(SocketIoProcesso r.java:198)
at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.access$400(SocketIoProce ssor.java:45)
at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor$Worker.run(SocketIoProce ssor.java:485)
at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:51)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
at sun.security.ssl.EngineInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(Unknown Source)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.mina.filter.support.SSLHandler.unwrap0(SSLHandler.java:668)
at org.apache.mina.filter.support.SSLHandler.unwrapHandshake(SSLHandler.java:624)
at org.apache.mina.filter.support.SSLHandler.handshake(SSLHandler.java:503)
at org.apache.mina.filter.support.SSLHandler.messageReceived(SSLHandler.java:306)
at org.apache.mina.filter.SSLFilter.messageReceived(SSLFilter.java:392)
... 14 more
2016.08.24 07:24:56 org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.ConnectionHandler - ConnectionHandler reports IOException for session: (SOCKET, R: /70.198.72.125:5016, L: /172.16.23.40:5222, S: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:5222)
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake failed.
at org.apache.mina.filter.SSLFilter.messageReceived(SSLFilter.java:416)
at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(Ab stractIoFilterChain.java:299)
at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain.access$1100(AbstractIoFilt erChain.java:53)
at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceive d(AbstractIoFilterChain.java:648)
at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain$HeadFilter.messageReceived (AbstractIoFilterChain.java:499)
at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(Ab stractIoFilterChain.java:299)
at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain.fireMessageReceived(Abstra ctIoFilterChain.java:293)
at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.read(SocketIoProcessor.j ava:228)
at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.process(SocketIoProcesso r.java:198)
at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.access$400(SocketIoProce ssor.java:45)
at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor$Worker.run(SocketIoProce ssor.java:485)
at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:51)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-97.117
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.checkRecordVersion(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.EngineInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(Unknown Source)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.mina.filter.support.SSLHandler.unwrap0(SSLHandler.java:668)
at org.apache.mina.filter.support.SSLHandler.unwrapHandshake(SSLHandler.java:624)
at org.apache.mina.filter.support.SSLHandler.handshake(SSLHandler.java:503)
at org.apache.mina.filter.support.SSLHandler.messageReceived(SSLHandler.java:306)
at org.apache.mina.filter.SSLFilter.messageReceived(SSLFilter.java:392)
... 14 more
```

Please let me know if more information is needed from my side.

**Update:** 
Here are some more client side logs that may provide some more information.

```
09-14 02:09:07.130 10994 12986 D SMACK   : SENT (0): <iq to='controlroom@conference.myapp.com' id='JQYId-1396' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner'></query></iq>
09-14 02:09:07.230 10994 12987 D SMACK   : RECV (0): <iq type="error" id="JQYId-1396" from="controlroom@conference.myapp.com" to="eaf60f002867230766bb74b4419dffca@myapp.com/d73d639de6435579"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner"/><error code="403" type="auth"><forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>

09-14 02:09:07.250 10994 11433 D SMACK   : XMPPConnection reconnected (0)

09-14 02:09:08.960 10994 10994 W ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.myapp.xmpptest-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.myapp.xmpptest rsrc of package null
09-14 02:09:09.180 10994 10994 D myapp   : getApplicationPackage : com.myapp.xmpptest
09-14 02:09:09.210 10994 10994 I XmppService: UserName from preferences : harit.mehta1@hotmail.com

09-14 02:09:09.220 10994 13097 I XmppService: Before xmppConnection connect.....
09-14 02:09:09.220 10994 13097 I XmppService: Before xmppConnection login.....

09-14 02:09:10.560 10994 10994 I Choreographer: Skipped 74 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-14 02:09:11.070 10994 10994 I Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@a12e696 time:5117900
09-14 02:09:28.900 10994 10994 V ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{fe7fff6 token=android.os.BinderProxy@a12e696 {com.myapp.xmpptest/com.myapp.xmpptest.DashFragmentActivity}} show : false

09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W AbstractXMPPConnection: Connection closed with error
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W AbstractXMPPConnection: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x9bf6cd80: I/O error during system call, Connection timed out
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W AbstractXMPPConnection:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W AbstractXMPPConnection:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:811)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W AbstractXMPPConnection:    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:233)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W AbstractXMPPConnection:    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:325)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W AbstractXMPPConnection:    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.ObservableReader.read(ObservableReader.java:41)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W AbstractXMPPConnection:    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.fillBuffer(KXmlParser.java:1515)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W AbstractXMPPConnection:    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.peekType(KXmlParser.java:992)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W AbstractXMPPConnection:    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:349)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W AbstractXMPPConnection:    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:313)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W AbstractXMPPConnection:    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1173)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W AbstractXMPPConnection:    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:952)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W AbstractXMPPConnection:    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:967)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W AbstractXMPPConnection:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 D myapp   : XmppConnectionListener connectionClosedOnError()

09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x9bf6cd80: I/O error during system call, Connection timed out
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:811)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:233)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:325)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.ObservableReader.read(ObservableReader.java:41)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.fillBuffer(KXmlParser.java:1515)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.peekType(KXmlParser.java:992)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:349)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:313)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1173)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:952)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:967)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 D SMACK   : XMPPConnection closed due to an exception (0)

09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x9bf6cd80: I/O error during system call, Connection timed out
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:811)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:233)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:325)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.ObservableReader.read(ObservableReader.java:41)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.fillBuffer(KXmlParser.java:1515)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.peekType(KXmlParser.java:992)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:349)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:313)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1173)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:952)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:967)
09-14 02:09:46.200 10994 12987 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

09-14 02:09:47.320 10994 14484 D SMACK   : XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 19
09-14 02:09:48.360 10994 14484 D SMACK   : XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 18
09-14 02:09:49.400 10994 14484 D SMACK   : XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 17

09-14 02:09:50.170 10994 10994 W ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.myapp.xmpptest-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.myapp.xmpptest rsrc of package null
09-14 02:09:50.400 10994 10994 D myapp   : getApplicationPackage : com.myapp.xmpptest
09-14 02:09:50.430 10994 10994 I XmppService: UserName from preferences : harit.mehta1@hotmail.com

09-14 02:09:50.440 10994 14484 D SMACK   : XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 16
09-14 02:09:50.440 10994 14662 I XmppService: Before xmppConnection connect.....
09-14 02:09:51.440 10994 14484 D SMACK   : XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 15
09-14 02:09:52.440 10994 14484 D SMACK   : XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 14
09-14 02:09:52.460 10994 10994 I Choreographer: Skipped 115 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-14 02:09:53.440 10994 14484 D SMACK   : XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 13

09-14 02:09:53.500 10994 10994 I Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@a12e696 time:5160339

09-14 02:09:53.680 10994 14774 D SMACK   : SENT (0): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='myapp.com' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='eaf60f002867230766bb74b4419dffca@myapp.com' xml:lang='en'>
09-14 02:09:53.740 10994 14775 D SMACK   : RECV (0): <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="myapp.com" id="b894b7e" xml:lang="en" version="1.0">
09-14 02:09:53.800 10994 14775 D SMACK   : RECV (0): <stream:features><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"><required/></starttls><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>

09-14 02:09:53.800 10994 14774 D SMACK   : SENT (0): <starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'></starttls>
09-14 02:09:53.870 10994 14775 D SMACK   : RECV (0): <proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>

09-14 02:09:54.250 10994 14774 D SMACK   : SENT (0): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='myapp.com' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='eaf60f002867230766bb74b4419dffca@myapp.com' xml:lang='en'>
09-14 02:09:54.300 10994 14775 D SMACK   : RECV (0): <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="myapp.com" id="b894b7e" xml:lang="en" version="1.0"><stream:features><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression><auth xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth"/></stream:features>

09-14 02:09:54.310 10994 14662 D myapp   : XmppConnectionListener connectionConnected()

09-14 02:09:54.310 10994 14662 D SMACK   : XMPPConnection connected (0)
09-14 02:09:54.330 10994 14774 D SMACK   : SENT (0): <auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='PLAIN'>lkdhfgkhfdltsyireghjHASHKhfhioqethrh275984758hgjksdhg894q39kHKHIG89Y5HDFJKGNJKSY4E893HKJFHDUYST4HJHWA7389J5KLHFH97jkj97uotigdkhgfd8976i3qkH9786OI45H6TJKHIA7OTI3I4WHTLIURFUIY9==</auth>

09-14 02:09:54.440 10994 14484 D SMACK   : XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 12
09-14 02:09:54.440 10994 14484 D SMACK   : XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 0

09-14 02:09:59.380 10994 14774 D SMACK   : SENT (0): <auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='PLAIN'>lkdhfgkhfdltsyireghjHASHKhfhioqethrh275984758hgjksdhg894q39kHKHIG89Y5HDFJKGNJKSY4E893HKJFHDUYST4HJHWA7389J5KLHFH97jkj97uotigdkhgfd8976i3qkH9786OI45H6TJKHIA7OTI3I4WHTLIURFUIY9==</auth>

09-14 02:09:59.380 10994 14662 W System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'.
09-14 02:09:59.390 10994 14662 W System.err:    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:250)
09-14 02:09:59.390 10994 14662 W System.err:    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.loginNonAnonymously(XMPPTCPConnection.java:374)
09-14 02:09:59.390 10994 14662 W System.err:    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:456)
09-14 02:09:59.390 10994 14662 W System.err:    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:414)
09-14 02:09:59.390 10994 14662 W System.err:    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:863)
09-14 02:09:59.390 10994 14662 W System.err:    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:364)
09-14 02:09:59.390 10994 14662 W System.err:    at com.myapp.xmpp.XmppService.connectAndAuthenticate(XmppService.java:591)
09-14 02:09:59.390 10994 14662 W System.err:    at com.myapp.xmpp.XmppService$2.run(XmppService.java:217)
09-14 02:09:59.390 10994 14662 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-14 02:09:59.410 10994 14662 D Utilities: Xmpp Log Files directory created : true
09-14 02:09:59.800 10994 14662 D Utilities: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Log file saved. returning~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
09-14 02:09:59.800 10994 14662 I XmppService: Before xmppConnection login.....
```

It seems like the client never receives the response to 'auth' stanza. After looking at the code in smack library I think the code below in the 'connectInternal()' method in 'XMPPTCPConnection.java' might be causing this error. I think that when the connect method is still in the handshake process, the login is called which might be messing things up on the server. Should there be some delay before we call login till the handshake process is complete? If so how do I fix this issue? If not then what might be causing the timeout error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The server side exception is very common in production logs when you are serving mobile clients. Which clearly states that on mobile devices our network keeps on switching and it's different from a desktop LAN/WiFi connection which doesn't connect/disconnect that often.

So your particular case seems one, and you can control this with reconnect policy which i believe you are already doing.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I thought no one was going to help me out here :)  Your answer does clear some doubts regarding the server side logs but I am still don't understand what is causing the timeout exceptions "No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'." on the client side. I am adding the latest client side logs after the server logs above. I would really appreciate it if you could help me out here. Thanks.

Comment: Are you checking if device is connected to wifi or data properly or not. Using connectivitymanager if its connected or not?

Comment: Yes I try to connect from the networkMonitor that monitors the network connectivity and listens to android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE and is as defined in the code above. Am I supposed to check for anything else? Thanks